# Why the vertical line coordinates vary?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am trying to extract text from tables using openCV and Azure read. The goal is to extract text column wise. So the first step to perform is detect vertical lines in the image(table). Now using the coordinates of these vertical lines as extreme boundaries we identify the text in between these lines.

Thus obtaining text based on Vertical Line Filter based.

Although the script is working fine, I observed a scenario where the line coordinates occur inappropriately for one particular type(Type A) of tables. So after debugging we observed the issue is with the heading part of tables(only for Type A).

So when we eliminated(cropped the image) the heading part of the tables( of Type A), the vertical line coordinates are appropriate.

The formatting of coordinates is as (x,y,w,h). 
 x and y are the top most point of a vertical line. 
 w is width of line.(in vertical lines it is almost 2pixel maximum).
 h is height of vertical line.

Here i am attaching two scenarios:
 1. Table with headings   - giving wrong coordinates.
      [Actual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVoVg.png), [Binarized Vertical lines of Actual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3toh.png)

coordinates of vertical lines with headings(left to right) - 
[(9, 0, 14, 439), (213, 0, 93, 426), (337, 28, 1, 398), (397, 29, 1, 410), (470, 29, 1, 397), (522, 0, 12, 439)]

2. Table without headings- giving appropriate coordinates. 
     [Image without headings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK0wu.png), [Without headings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpHhD.png)

coordinates of vertical lines without headings(left to right)-
[(7, 0, 1, 404), (303, 0, 1, 391), (335, 0, 1, 391), (395, 0, 1, 404), (468, 0, 1, 391), (531, 0, 1, 404)]

We can observe the coordinates of second line are varying a lot while other lines are close. 
So the issue is, second vertical line coordinates are improper in image with headings. What could be the reason?

Comment: Show your code.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of the threshold value specified for filtering out the vertical lines.
[image: Results]

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2 as cv

def show_wait_destroy(winname, img):
    cv.imshow(winname, img)
    cv.moveWindow(winname, 500, 0)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyWindow(winname)

def main(argv):
    # [load_image]
    # Check number of arguments
    if len(argv) < 1:
        print ('Not enough parameters')
        print ('Usage:\nmorph_lines_detection.py < path_to_image >')
        return -1
    # Load the image
    src = cv.imread(argv[0], cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
    # Check if image is loaded fine
    if src is None:
        print ('Error opening image: ' + argv[0])
        return -1
    # Show source image
    cv.imshow("src", src)
    # [load_image]
    # [gray]
    # Transform source image to gray if it is not already
    if len(src.shape) != 2:
        gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
        gray = src
    # Show gray image
    show_wait_destroy("gray", gray)
    # [gray]
    # [bin]
    # Apply adaptiveThreshold at the bitwise_not of gray, notice the ~ symbol
    gray = cv.bitwise_not(gray)
    bw = cv.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, \
                                cv.THRESH_BINARY, 15, -2)
    # Show binary image
    show_wait_destroy("binary", bw)
    # [bin]
    # [init]
    # Create the images that will use to extract the horizontal and vertical lines
    horizontal = np.copy(bw)
    vertical = np.copy(bw)
    # [init]
    # [horiz]
    # Specify size on horizontal axis
    cols = horizontal.shape[1]
    horizontal_size = cols // 30
    # Create structure element for extracting horizontal lines through morphology operations
    horizontalStructure = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (horizontal_size, 1))
    # Apply morphology operations
    horizontal = cv.erode(horizontal, horizontalStructure)
    horizontal = cv.dilate(horizontal, horizontalStructure)
    # Show extracted horizontal lines
    show_wait_destroy("horizontal", horizontal)
    # [horiz]
    # [vert]
    # Specify size on vertical axis
    rows = vertical.shape[0]
    verticalsize = rows // 10 #####--->>>>>This decides the threshold for vertical line
    # Create structure element for extracting vertical lines through morphology operations
    verticalStructure = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (1, verticalsize))
    # Apply morphology operations
    vertical = cv.erode(vertical, verticalStructure)
    vertical = cv.dilate(vertical, verticalStructure)
    # Show extracted vertical lines
    show_wait_destroy("vertical", vertical)
    # [vert]
    # [smooth]
    # Inverse vertical image
    vertical = cv.bitwise_not(vertical)
    show_wait_destroy("vertical_bit", vertical)
    '''
    Extract edges and smooth image according to the logic
    1. extract edges
    2. dilate(edges)
    3. src.copyTo(smooth)
    4. blur smooth img
    5. smooth.copyTo(src, edges)
    '''
    # Step 1
    edges = cv.adaptiveThreshold(vertical, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, \
                                cv.THRESH_BINARY, 3, -2)
    show_wait_destroy("edges", edges)
    # Step 2
    kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
    edges = cv.dilate(edges, kernel)
    show_wait_destroy("dilate", edges)
    # Step 3
    smooth = np.copy(vertical)
    # Step 4
    smooth = cv.blur(smooth, (2, 2))
    # Step 5[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    (rows, cols) = np.where(edges != 0)
    vertical[rows, cols] = smooth[rows, cols]
    # Show final result
    show_wait_destroy("smooth - final", vertical)
    # [smooth]
    return 0
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
    ####to run the script use >>>>python image.py path/to/image
```

Comment: Thank you Aadil Srivastava. The Adaptive tresholding technique helped in removing small noises in the heading part. That decluttered the heading part. This made process simpler in computing the line coordinates.